# The parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied where the value is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have a problem with updating a SQL Server table from a DataGridView in the VB.Net, I know that the exception that I had is because of Null value but I'm sure that the value is set with a valid value, here is the code:

```
cmd.CommandText = _
    "update BillItem set Item=@item1,Quantity=@q1,Price=@price1,TotalPrice=@tp1,BillID=@billId1 where Id=@id1"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@item1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@q1", SqlDbType.Int)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@price1", SqlDbType.Float)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tp1", SqlDbType.Float)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@billId1", SqlDbType.Int)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id1", SqlDbType.Int)

connection.Open()
cmd.Connection = connection

For i As Integer = 0 To 1
    cmd.Parameters(0).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
    cmd.Parameters(1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
    cmd.Parameters(2).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
    cmd.Parameters(3).Value = Integer.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value) * Double.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
    cmd.Parameters(4).Value = Integer.Parse(CurrentBillIDLbl.Text)
    cmd.Parameters(5).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
connection.Close()
```

Here is the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: The parameterized query '(@item nvarchar(4),@quantity int,@price float,@tp float,@billId ' expects the parameter '@q1', which was not supplied.

Comment: Why are you not parsing all the numeric values? This could be the reason.

Comment: Using the DGV and DB ops in general are intended to be much simpler than that - especially with regards to fishing data out of the right row bit by bit. I am not certain that code matches that error message

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes , I'm sure I'm entering a valid value, any way I try the parsing but it did not solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CommandText` parameters do not match the actual parameters as seen in the error message. The actual query thinks has `@item` but your example has `@item1`. Likewise, `@q1` is not `@quantity`. 
I don't think the code you have shown is in context, you are not using the command text that you think you are.

Comment: I Found it ! the CommandText was used before for another query! so the issue was solved by using a new CommandText

Comment: Yet another problem caused by reusing global DB Objects